# SQL query : Sum a column (not the date column) for day, week to date, month to date, etc

Tags: sql, case-when

I am wondering if there is a way within one SQL statement if you can break out a sum of a total column by date, week to date, month to date, etc.

Sample data

```
DataDate       TimeInterval          TotalCalls
9/1/2014        12:00                  154
9/1/2014        15:15                   25 
9/2/2014        07:30                  125             
9/3/2014        11:45                    8
9/8/2014        10:15                   15  
9/9/2014        19:30                    6
9/9/2014        12:15                  100
```

In this case, I would want the select statement to return the following data for a given date of `9/9/2014` and week starting on `Monday, 9/8/2014`

```
     Time Interval     SumofCalls
         Today            106
         WTD              121
         MTD              433
```

I have thought a `CASE WHEN` would work,  but I can only find examples of how to use a `CASE WHEN` to sum the count of the date column being queried against the criteria.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: What`s your database?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it in SQL Server using `UNION` and getting each range.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f77a1/2)**

```
DECLARE @today DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

SELECT 'Today' AS 'TimeInterval', 
    SUM(TotalCalls) AS 'SumOfCalls'
FROM yourTable 
WHERE DataDate = @today
UNION ALL

SELECT 'WTD', 
    SUM(TotalCalls)
FROM yourTable
WHERE DataDate BETWEEN dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, @today), 0) AND @today
UNION ALL

SELECT 'MTD', 
    SUM(TotalCalls)
FROM yourTable
WHERE DataDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@today)-1),@today) AND @today
```

If you could have the times periods go across the top as columns instead of rows then you could use `CASE`.